How can I prove triangle inequality for the following metric?
$$d: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow [0,1] $$
$$d(a,b) = min\{|a-b|, 1\}$$
where $|a-b|$ denotes the usual Euclidean Metric for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Welcome to MSE. Here's how to ask a good question. Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Take any $x,y, a$.  We want to prove that $d(x,y) \le d(x,a) + d(a, y)$.
Here's the trick.
We only have to consider if $d(x,a) + d(a,y) \ge 1$ or $d(x,a) + d(a,y) < 1$.
If $d(x,a) + d(a,y) \ge 1$ we are done as $d(x,y) \le 1\le d(x,a)+d(a,y)$.
And if $d(x,a) + d(a,y) < 1$ then we must have $|x-a|, |a-y|,$ and $|x-y| < 1$ and the whole thing resorts to the usual euclidean metric in which the triangle inequality holds.
....
Details.
Case 1:  If $d(x,a) + d(a,y)\ge 1$ then $d(x,y) =\min(|x-y|, 1) \le 1 \le d(x,a)+d(a,y)$.  Nothing more needs to be said.
Case 2: $d(x,a)+d(a,y) < 1$.  As both are non-negative each must be less than $1$.  But $d(x,a) = \min(|x-a|, 1)$ and if $\min(|x-a|, 1) < 1$ then we must have $\min(|x-a|, 1)$ be equal to $|x-a|$ and $|x-a| < 1$.So $d(x,a) = |x-a|< 1$ and $d(a,y) =|a-y| < 1$.
And by the good ol' fashioned Triangle inequality on the Euclidean metric we know.  $|x-y| \le |x-a| +|a-y|$.  But $|x-a| + |a-y| = d(x,a) + d(a,y) < 1$.  So $|x-y| < 1$.  And so $d(x,y)=\min(|x-y|, 1) =|x-y|$.
And that's that.... $d(x,y) = |x-y| < |x-a| + |a-y| = d(x,a) + d(a,y)$.

You should be able to do casework. We are trying to prove the following:
$d(x,y) \leq d(x,z) + d(z,y)$ for all $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$
If all $d(x,y)$, $d(x,z)$, and $d(z,y)$ are less than $1$, the triangle inequality comes from the fact that they are just the standard Euclidean metric. If either $d(x,z)$ or $d(z,y)$ is $1$, since $d(x,y) \leq 1$ and
$d(x,z) + d(z,y) \geq 1$ we have the triangle inequality. Therefore, we just look at the cases where both $d(x,z), d(z,y) < 1$ and $d(x,y) = 1 \leq |x-y|$. Then we get that $d(x,z) + d(z,y) = |x-z| + |z-y| \geq |x-y| \geq 1$. Therefore, all the 8 cases are covered.

To prove this, we need only to prove $\forall\;a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, we have $\min(|a-c|,1)\leq\min(|a-b|,1)+\min(|b-c|,1)$.
If $\min(|a-b|,1)=1$ or $\min(|b-c|,1)=1$, we have $\min(|a-b|,1)+\min(|b-c|,1)\geq 1\geq\min(|a-c|,1)$.
If $\min(|a-b|,1)\neq 1$ and $\min(|b-c|,1)\neq 1$, we have $\min(|a-b|,1)=|a-b|\leq 1$ and $\min(|b-c|,1)=|b-c|\leq 1$. Then a) if $|a-b|+|b-c|\geq 1$, by $1\geq\min(|a-c|,1)$, we have $\min(|a-b|,1)+\min(|b-c|,1)\geq 1\geq\min(|a-c|,1)$. b) If $|a-b|+|b-c|\leq 1$, by the triangle inequality, $|a-c|\leq |a-b|+|b-c|\leq 1$, which implies $|a-c|=\min(|a-c|,1)$ and thus $\min(|a-c|,1)\leq\min(|a-b|,1)+\min(|b-c|,1)$.
